# Fitting a "pseudo" discrete dataset

Tags: distributions, fitting, mixture-distribution, continuous-data

I'm working with a dataset that contains information about consumption of apples. The dataset contains the amount of apple consumed in g/day. The problem with this is that the data points fall into 3 categories:
- a real number (e.g. 54 g/day, people weighing their consumption) 
- a discrete number (number of apples per day), which is converted to g/day using the average weight of an apple (+/- 100g)
- 0, people not consuming any apples

A histogram of the data looks like this:
[image: Histogram]

Any tips on either transforming this data into something analyzable or fitting a distribution would be greatly appreciated.

I want to use this data to perform a risk analysis. For this we need to fit a distribution to the values and then sample from this distribution. The classic distributions included in the software I use (@Risk) obviously deliver horrible performance (as measured by AIC/BIC criteria)

Comment: What do you want the analysis to tell you? What question are you trying to answer?

Comment: The data are analyzable. They are just irregular in detail. Your measurements will imply a spiky distribution, but that need not inhibit or prohibit any serious analysis. They look awkward, but that is less of a problem than may appear. Your graph (straight out of MS Excel?) would look better with touching bars and bins with "nicer" intervals, e.g. 0-49, 50-99, ..., but those are matters of convention or cosmetics, and you will still get gaps in a display. So, there are outliers, people trying to overdose on apples. That's part of the information.

Comment: I can make the graph nicer by plotting the density in R but it was just to give a general idea.

It makes sense to transform this data into something truly discreet. I'm just worried I'll compromise my analysis results this way.

Comment: It's trite but true that we can only answer what you write. Distribution fitting is tricky here. A simple but key point is that some people just don't eat apples, so the real distribution is likely to include a spike at zero. Otherwise, who knows? Gamma? Lognormal?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers. Would a multimodal distribution make sense here? Several 'classes' of people: non-apple eaters, moderate eaters, enthusiasts, apple-crazy,... with their own mean and variation.

Comment: I don't have experience with this kind of data, but my instinct is that spike at zero and skewed but positive distribution is the way to go. Your data arrive lumpy or spiky; that's not a bug, but it's not a feature either, unless the spikes are maintained in really large samples (thousands or greater, roughly).

Comment: There is a problem logically prior to distribution fitting or making distributional assumptions, so let's bring it to the fore: the question concerns *how to compare distinctly different forms of measurement of the same thing.* One possible concern is there could be a systematic difference between the risks to those who weigh apples and those who just count them. To avoid this confounding, one option is not to attempt a count-to-weight conversion at all, but just treat counts and weights as different kinds of things altogether.

Comment: Whuber: the point you make is a good one indeed. I've been thinking this through and the most logical thing to me would be to discretize the data into a histogram, i.e. P(X=0), P(0<X<=1),P(1<X<=2),... and then just sample from this. This way I reduce the variance of the weighed group. As the data need not be analysed further for my purposes the reduction in information is not important.